# Is there a way to select a certain letter in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables, selection, letter

[image]

```
dna="AAGAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTCTTAGCGGGGCCACATCGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGTTACAGCGAGCATAC"
```

So basically I was trying to select ONLY the letter "C"s in the `dna` variable, and simply replace it with the letter "G".

Is there a way/function I can have for this? Would be greatly appreciated if answered!

Comment: You'll need to do more than that to reverse complement your sequence ;)

Comment: If you first replace all the `C` -> `G` how will you then replace all the `G` -> `C` ? Ex: `"CGCG".replace('C', 'G')` results in `"GGGG"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans)

Since you need:
C <-> G and A <-> T

Meaning C -> G and G -> C, etc.

**Example**

```
dna = "CGATCCGG" # dna sequence

# Create translation table
x = "CGAT"       # original letters
y = "GCTA"       # letters to map too
mytable = str.maketrans(x, y)  # Create translation table
                               # dna.maketrans(x, y) also works

# Apply table to dna string
translated = dna.translate(mytable)

# Show Original vs. translated
print(f"Original:\t{dna}\nTranslate:\t{translated}")
# Output:
Original:   CGATCCGG
Translate:  GCTAGGCC
```

Comment: @KellyBundy -- to create table you can either use an instance of a string (i.e. dna.maketrans...) or string class str (i.e. str.maketrans...).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp -- good point, expanded tabke with your suggestion.

Comment: Love you! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.replace()`:

```py
dna=("AAGAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTCT"
"TAGCGGGGCCACATCGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGTTACAGCGAGCATAC")

print(dna.replace("C", "G"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace Cs with Gs, use this:

```py
dna.replace('C', 'G')
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score -1):

for general replacement, you can use `str.replace(target, replacement)` but the issue in the context of the problem is that if you string replace all the C's with G's, you don't know what was originally a G to replace to a C to get the compliment.

It would be better to convert the strand into a list, then replace values one by 1 with case blocks or if/else blocks:

```
def dna_compliment(strand):
  listStrand = list(strand)
  for i in range(len(listStrand)):
     if listStrand[i] == 'C':
        listStrand[i] = 'G'
     elif ...
     ...
  return ''.join(listStrand)
```